# Replace/remove a character in a string

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I looked it up and did find some help with this, but unfortunately they all use a function called replace(), which does not exist in the program I have to use.

```
def getWordList(minLength, maxLength):
    url = "http://wordlist.ca/list.txt"
    flink = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    # where the new code needs to be to strip away the extra symbol
    for eachline in flink:
        if minLength+2<= len(eachline) <=maxLength+2:
            WordList.append(eachline.strip())
    return(WordList)
```

Strings are immutable, so i need to create a new string for each word in the list with removing a character.

```
initialWordList = []
WordList = []
jj = 0
def getWordList(minLength, maxLength):
    url = "http://cs.umanitoba.ca/~comp1012/2of12inf.txt"
    flink = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    for eachline in flink:
        if minLength+2<= len(eachline) <=maxLength+2:
            initialWordList.append(eachline.strip())
    while jj<=len(initialWordList)-1:
        something something something replace '%' with ''
        WordList.append(initialWordList[jj])
        jj+=1
return(WordList)
```

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: it looks like you have solved the problem...

Comment: I said that the replace function does not work, nor does it exist in the program I have to use

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python strings are immutable, but they do have methods that return new strings

```
'for example'.replace('for', 'an')
```

returns

```
'an example'
```

You can remove a substring by replacing it with an empty string:

```
'for example'.replace('for ', '')
```

returns

```
'example'
```

To emphasize how methods work, they are functions that are builtin to string objects. They are also available as classmethods:

```
str.replace('for example', 'for ', '')
```

returns

```
'example'
```

So if you have a list of strings:

```
list_of_strings = ['for example', 'another example']
```

you can replace substrings in them with a `for` loop:

```
for my_string in list_of_strings:
    print(my_string.replace('example', 'instance'))
```

prints out:

```
for instance
another instance
```

Since strings are immutable, your list actually doesn't change (print it and see) but you can create a new list with a list comprehension:

```
new_list = [my_s.replace('example', 'instance') for my_s in list_of_strings]
print(new_list)
```

prints:

```
['for instance', 'another instance']
```

Comment: This business of the immutability of strings could be difficult to grasp initially, so I want to call it out. `foo = 'a%line'` followed by `foo.replace('%','')` does NOT modify the value of foo, it returns a new string whose value is `'aline'`. If you do not actually do anything with that return value, then it gets thrown away. If you want to update the value of foo, then you would have to write `foo = foo.replace('%', '')`. Or in your case, `my_list.append(foo.replace('%', ''))`. And, by the way, you can chain string-manipulation operations: `foo.strip().replace('%', '')`

Comment: the replace function does not exist in the program I have to use, and I cannot instal plugins to make it work

Comment: Bob, perhaps you're trying to use replace() as a standalone function? If so, know that it's a classmethod of str, and it should be available in any Python you use. I added a demonstration of using it as a classmethod as str.replace().

Comment: oh, okay. Now it is working, but how do I use this for a list of strings?

Comment: Ok, so does that show how you might do it for a list of strings?

Comment: it won't get rid of the % sign, so I just added the % sign to my dictionary with value 1. it buggers it up a bit, but I think i can push through